# How does String id = db.collection("myCollection").document().getId() gives document Id without hitting Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read somewhere that `db.collection("mycollection").document().getId();` gives document Id in `mycollection` without hitting cloudstore database. But how it is possible to create unique Id without knowing document id of already existing doucments or hitting couldstore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-ID that is generated when you call `document()` is a fairly basic UUID (universally unique identifier). Such identifier are statistically guaranteed to be unique. In my words: there is so much random information in there, that the chances of two calls generating the same value are infinitesimally small.

So Firestore doesn't actually call the server to check whether the ID it generates is unique. It instead relies on the mathematical properties of picking a single value out of a sufficiently large and random set to be very certain it is unique.